# Two values form field depending on selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

This is the basic form, they have a predefined value, which will be used to create a link, but My problem is that the values are different depending on location. Please help!

```
<input type="radio" id="iconapp1" name="department" value="1250"/><label for="iconapp1"></label>
<input type="radio" id="iconapp2" name="department" value="944"/ checked><label for="iconapp2">  </label>
<input type="radio" id="iconapp3" name="department" value="4"/><label for="iconapp3"></label>
<input type="radio" id="iconapp4" name="department" value="1254"/><label for="iconapp4"></label>


<input type="radio" id="enginemake1" name="enginemake" value="6" checked/><label for="enginemake1">Chevrolet</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="enginemake2" name="enginemake" value="8"/><label for="enginemake2">Chrysler</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="enginemake3" name="enginemake" value="7"/><label for="enginemake3">Ford</label><br>


<select id="powerrange" name="powerrange">
<option id="powerrange1" value="128">200 HP</option>
<option id="powerrange2" value="178">250 HP</option>
<option id="powerrange3" value="228" selected>300 HP</option>
<option id="powerrange4" value="278">350 HP</option>
</select>

<input type="radio" id="location1" name="location" value="store" checked/><label for="location1">America</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="location2" name="location" value="store.au"/><label for="location2">Australia</label><br>
```

I have this script which is working, It creates a link from the previous form, but my problem is that the values (department, Enginemake and power range) are different depending on the location.

For example if AMERICA selected Use Engine Make Value 1 if OCEANICA selected use Engine Make Value 2. is that possible??

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function goToPage(){
    var location = $('input[name=location]:checked').val();
    var department = $('input[name=department]:checked').val();
    var enginemake = $('input[name=enginemake]:checked').val();
    var powerrange = document.getElementById("powerrange").value;

    window.location.href = "http://"+location+".domain.com/catalog.aspx?section=-"+department+"-"+enginemake+"-"+powerrange+"-";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm.. What exactly is the question here?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trying to change the available values when a location is selected, or if you are trying to automatically select a value when location is selected

Comment: The question is: How to change the values from (Departmen, Enginemake and Powerrange) depending on the selection of Location field! the current one it's working with australia selected, but for America I need different values!

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to change the selection of another field on the click event of the "location" field?  If so, something like this inside `$(document).ready` would work:

```
$("input[name='location']").click(function(){
   switch($(this).val()){
      case 'store': 
        $("#enginemake").attr("checked", "true");
        break;
     //insert logic for other selections
   }
})
```

something similar could be done using `.hide()` and `.show()` instead of the `.attr()` call to make different options visible based on the selection.